# How do I convert a cursor's SELECT query to fully run within a PL/SQL stored procedure?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I have a slow stored procedure in Oracle 12 that I'd like to see if I can optimize.  It returns several query results as OUT cursors.  I thought I'd profile the procedure using the Profile tools in Allround PL/SQL Developer, but I realized executing the procedure doesn't evaluate (iterate through) the output cursors, so my profile will not give me anything interesting.

How do I modify my stored procedure to simply fully evaluate the cursors?  In SQL Server, the procedure could just have naked SELECT statements in it, but it looks like that isn't possible in PL/SQL procedures.  **How do I modify the PL/SQL for a cursor's SELECT query to fully evaluate the SELECT within a PL/SQL stored procedure** so that I can profile the procedure holistically?

I think I'm struggling with the Oracle paradigm as opposed to SQL Server, so if I am thinking about this wrong, would love to hear it.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_my_proc(
        /* ... */
        out_my_cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) IS 
    BEGIN 
        /* ... */
        OPEN out_my_cursor FOR
        SELECT ... FROM ... ; -- I want to profile this whole proc including this SELECT
    END sp_my_proc;
```

Comment: Use `EXPLAIN PLAN FOR SELECT ... FROM ... ;`

Comment: That doesn't help me to optimize the whole stored procedure, right?  I really want the plan for everything in a procedure, as I need to compare the various parts--not any individual SELECT.  I gather that profiling tools is what I need, thus my question above.

Comment: you can use profiler or hprof?

Comment: I can use profiler or hprof to fully evaluate the SELECT within a PL/SQL stored procedure?  That seems unlikely.

Comment: The profiler only profiles what the procedure does, It appears that the procedure doesn't fetch the rows. If most of the time is spent fetching rows from the cursors returned, then you don't have a slow procedure, you have slow cursors.

Comment: Which brings me back to the same question.  How do I convert the cursors to SELECTs that execute inside the procedure so that I can profile them?

Comment: PL/SQL Dev will fetch any cursor you like and display the results in a grid, and while it's doing that you can use the session browser to inspect the plan, run a SQL Monitor report, check the objects accessed in v$active_session_history (if licenced) and so on. What's wrong with that?

Answer (score 1):

Here a minimal example, how you can fetch all rows from the returned cursor in PL/SQL.

Add your input parameters and additional column returned in the cursor

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_my_proc(
    out_my_cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) IS 
BEGIN 
    OPEN out_my_cursor FOR
    SELECT rownum ID FROM dual connect by level <= 5; 
END sp_my_proc;
/    


declare
cv_out sys_refcursor; 
--  
v_id   NUMBER;
begin
         sp_my_proc(cv_out);
         /* to read the cursor use fetch in a loop */
         LOOP
            FETCH cv_out INTO v_id;
            EXIT WHEN cv_out%NOTFOUND;
            dbms_output.put_line( 'ID= '|| v_ID   ); 
        END LOOP;       
end;
/
```

**While fetching rows from a cursor the main difficulty is in defining the varibale in the `FETCH  INTO`  clause.**

Oracle provides two options to simplify this task.

If the cursor columns corresponds 1:1 to a table or view you may use [table_or_view_name%ROWTYPE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/composites.htm#GUID-9D20CCCC-E34B-473B-8499-4787D17C1980)

example

```
v_cur   tab%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN 
    OPEN out_my_cursor FOR
    SELECT col1, col2 FROM tab;  /* tab has two columns */
```

More offen you will need the general case [cursor%ROWTYPE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/composites.htm#GUID-064DACC4-4F40-43CA-9518-09F0BE5923EB)

But unfortunately this can't be used with dynamic cursor, so you must declare the cursor explicitely (copy it from the procedure)

```
declare
 CURSOR cur is
    SELECT col1, col2 FROM tab;  /* tab has more than two columns */
 v_cur cur%ROWTYPE;
begin
         OPEN cur;
         LOOP
            FETCH cur INTO v_cur;
            EXIT WHEN cur%NOTFOUND;
             dbms_output.put_line( 'col1= '|| v_cur.col1   );
         END LOOP;       
end;
/
```

Comment: I'll try it.  Is there any way to do the same within the stored procedure rather than after running it?

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski not sure what are you asking. A procedure that *returns a cursor* only open it and you must `fetch` the data *from  outside of the procedure*. And yes, there are cursors that open quickly and spends years while fetching the rows.

Comment: if `cv_out` returns a row rather than a NUMBER, how do I declare `v_id`?  (or how do I just discard the data without anything to hold it?)

Comment: Simple declare all cursor columns as single variables and use `FETCH cv_out INTO v_id, v_col2, v_col3,....`. You must fetch **all columns** to be able to compile (no discard possible).

Comment: That's a lot of work for data that I am just discarding.  Any way to DECLARE the whole row as one variable?  Maybe with `%ROWTYPE` somehow?

Comment: Thus why I want to evaluate these cursors within the procedure--I don't want to deal with dozens of variables.  Know any way to make a SELECT run in the procedure without returning it as a cursor?

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski you must realize, if the *procedure execution* is slow or if the *fething* of the cursors is the problem. A look at the **ASH View** could provide first information so see if the time is consumed in PL/SQL or SQL. Good luck!

Comment: The fetching of the data for the cursor is the problem, which is why I want to run the query inside the procedure without a cursor so that I can profile it. But how?

Comment: That is, I believe the slowness is in data fetching and not in PL/SQL per se. If I could profile several SELECTs inside a proc, I could see which one has the biggest share of the slowness.